# Demo of compaction for Parquet bulk format

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Since version 1.15 of Apache Flink you can use the compaction feature to merge several files into one. [flink compaction](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/filesystem/#compaction)

so,i wrote a demo about compaction of flink sink
quote by [use-of-compaction-for-parquet-bulk-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72716885/use-of-compaction-for-parquet-bulk-format)
its works,but the result will be many compacted files not one:
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMH4N.png)

my code is:

```
FileSink<GenericRecord> sink = FileSink.forBulkFormat(
                        new Path(outputPath),
                        AvroParquetWriters.forGenericRecord(schema))
                .withRollingPolicy(OnCheckpointRollingPolicy.build())
                .enableCompact(
                        FileCompactStrategy.Builder.newBuilder()
                                .setSizeThreshold(50000)
                                .enableCompactionOnCheckpoint(10)
                                .setSizeThreshold(5)
                                .build(),
                        new RecordWiseFileCompactor<>(
                                new InputFormatBasedReader.Factory<>(new SerializableSupplierWithException<FileInputFormat<GenericRecord>, IOException>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public FileInputFormat<GenericRecord> get() throws IOException {
                                        return new ExampleFileInputFormat();
                                    }
                                })
                        ))
//                .withBucketAssigner(dateTimeBucketAssigner)
                .withBucketAssigner(new BucketAssigner<GenericRecord, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String getBucketId(GenericRecord genericRecord, Context context) {
                        return genericRecord.get("today").toString();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public SimpleVersionedSerializer<String> getSerializer() {
                        return SimpleVersionedStringSerializer.INSTANCE;
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

I want to know if the results are correct ？？？